isomorphism of two concrete D-modules
Recently, I've been self-learning the theory of D-modules and came across an exercise in Professor Christian Schnell's notes which I can't figure out.
Here is my attempt. Considering the $A_{1}$ module map
$\phi: A_{1}^2\to A_{1},(P_{1},P_{2})\mapsto P_{1} + P_{2}\partial$. We can easily check that this map leads to an $A_{1}$ module map from $M_{1}\to M_{2}$, and it is a surjection.
But I can't prove that it is injective. I wonder if the map I constructed is an isomorphism.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

First of all note that
$$
M_1=A_1^2/A_1((\partial,-1),(c,a\partial+b)).
$$
Define the map $\psi\colon A_1\to A_1^2$ by $\psi(R)=(R(1+c),R(a\partial+b))$. Since
$$
\psi(a\partial^2+b\partial+c)=((a\partial^2+b\partial+c)(1+c),(a\partial^2+b\partial+c)(a\partial+b))=\\
(a\partial+b)\cdot(\partial,-1)+(a\partial^2+b\partial+c+1)\cdot(c,a\partial+b)\in
A_1((\partial,-1),(c,a\partial+b)),
$$
we see that $\psi$ induces a map of modules $M_2\to M_1$, and since
$$
\phi(\psi(R))=\phi(R(1+c),R(a\partial+b))=
R(1+c)+R(a\partial^2+b\partial)=R\pmod{A_1(a\partial^2+b\partial+c)}
$$
and
$$
\psi(\phi(P,Q))=\psi(P+Q\partial)=((P+Q\partial)(1+c),(P+Q\partial)(a\partial+b))=\\
(P,Q)+Q\cdot(\partial,-1)+(P+Q\partial)\cdot(c,a\partial+b)=(P,Q)
\pmod{A_1((\partial,-1),(c,a\partial+b))},
$$
this map is a two-sided inverse to the map of modules induced by $\phi$.
